# How to explain "the factory got flooded"

Tags: phrase-meaning

[Reading 7 tips to prevent the “different bank accounts” scam](http://www.qualityinspection.org/bank-info-scam-china/), I came across this sentence: (e.g. “the factory got flooded”).

> 1. Get to know several English speakers for each supplier
>
>    Get their company landline phone numbers (even Skype accounts can be hacked). If something suspicious comes up, you can give a few phone calls and get several people’s versions. This will not only be helpful for payments, but also for other claims (e.g. “the factory got flooded”).

I think there’s a metaphor here, but I cannot get its meaning.

Would you please help me with its explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot open your link (network security at work...) but I would *guess* that the phrase "the factory got flooded" is not so much a metaphor, as it is a pastiche for a very standard excuse.

Compare it to the classic "my dog ate my homework" to explain why you cannot show your homework in class.

Someone who has taken your money but has no intention of delivering the goods may for some time (to gain time) give you excuses:

> the manufacturer experienced delays
>   there was a quality issue with this batch
>   the factory got flooded!

Comment: +1 I added the context, which appears to support your reading.